# THREE JS position from matrixWorld is same as local position

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I've imported a collada file from Cinema4D with a tree of parented objects. When I get an object's world position like so:

```
var thing = scene.getObjectByName("thing");
thing.updateMatrixWorld();
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3(); 
worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(thing.matrixWorld);
```

it is the same as `thing.position`, which the docs say is local position. I know this object has a parent with a non-zero position. When I try the same thing without `updateMatrixWorld()`, the world position is zero. How can I get the correct world position?

Comment: You have to update the world matrices of all of the object's ancestors, too. Depending on your situation, try `parent.updateMatrixWorld()` or `scene.updateMatrixWorld()`.

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to `updateMatrixWorld()` for each parent of my object, which I did like this:

```
function updateWorldMatrices (object)
{
    var parent = object;
    while (parent.parent != null)
    {
        parent.updateMatrixWorld();
        parent = parent.parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [updateWorldMatrix](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.updateWorldMatrix) now has parameters for updating parent and children.